# Retornar veículos que possuem todas peças em determinada tabela

Tags: sql, select

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, no meu banco de dados tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
|      veiculo      |
| idVeiculo | placa |

|        peca       |
| idPeca | nomePeca |

|      relVeiPec     |
| idVeiculo | idPeca |

| pecaObrig |
|   idPeca  |
```

Preciso de um **SELECT** na tabela *relVeiPec* que retorne os veículos que tenham todas as peças da tabela *pecaObrig*.

Já tentei com a clausula **IN**, mas ela retorna o veículo que tem **qualquer** peça da tabela *pecaObrig*, eu queria que retornasse o veículo que teria **todas** as pecas dessa tabela e não qualquer uma.

```
SELECT vp.idVeiculo, v.placa, vp.idPeca, p.nomePeca FROM relVeiPec AS vp
INNER JOIN veiculo AS v ON v.idVeiculo = vp.idVeiculo
INNER JOIN peca AS p ON p.idPeca = vp.idPeca
WHERE vp.idPeca IN (SELECT idPeca FROM pecaObrig)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query a baixo seria um exemplo de como fazer isso.

```
--|      veiculo      |
--| idVeiculo | placa |

--|        peca       |
--| idPeca | nomePeca |

--|      relVeiPec     |
--| idVeiculo | idPeca |

--| pecaObrig |
--|   idPeca  |

Declare @Veiculos table
(     
    idVeiculo int,  
    placa varchar(7)
);

insert into @Veiculos values 
(1,'AAA1111'), 
(2,'BBB2222'), 
(3,'CCC3333'), 
(4,'DDD4444');

Declare @Peca table
(     
    idPeca int,     
    nomePeca varchar(20)
);

insert into @Peca values 
(1,'porta'),  
(2,'vidro'), 
(3,'pneu'), 
(4,'Motor'), 
(5,'chassis'),  
(6,'parabrisa');

Declare @pecaObrig table 
(   
    idPeca int
);

insert into @pecaObrig values 
(1), 
(4), 
(5);

Declare @relVeiPec table
(    
    idVeiculo int, 
    idPeca int
)

insert into @relVeiPec values (1,1) ,(1,2) ,(1,3) ,(1,4) ,(1,5),(1,6),
(2,1) ,(2,2) ,(2,6),(3,1) ,(3,2),(3,4) ,(3,6),(4,1) ,(4,4) ,(4,5);

SELECT vp.idVeiculo, v.placa, vp.idPeca, p.nomePeca 
    FROM @relVeiPec AS vp
    INNER JOIN @Veiculos AS v 
        ON v.idVeiculo = vp.idVeiculo
    INNER JOIN @Peca AS p 
        ON p.idPeca = vp.idPeca
        WHERE v.idVeiculo in (
                    select idVeiculo 
                        from @pecaObrig po
                        join @relVeiPec rcp
                        on rcp.idPeca = po.idPeca
                        group by idVeiculo
                        having count(rcp.idPeca)  = (select count(*) from @pecaObrig)
                    )
```

Ou você pode usar o `EXISTS`  que é mais eficiente que o `IN`

```
SELECT vp.idVeiculo, v.placa, vp.idPeca, p.nomePeca 
FROM @relVeiPec AS vp
INNER JOIN @Veiculos AS v ON v.idVeiculo = vp.idVeiculo
INNER JOIN @Peca AS p ON p.idPeca = vp.idPeca
WHERE EXISTS  (
    select idVeiculo from @pecaObrig po
    join @relVeiPec rcp
    on rcp.idPeca = po.idPeca
    where idVeiculo = vp.idVeiculo
    group by idVeiculo
    having count(rcp.idPeca)  = (select count(*) from @pecaObrig)
```

Comment: Show, deu certo, irei dar uma estudada nessa sua ultima QUERY!

Answer (score 2):

***SQL:***

```
SELECT v.* FROM pecaobrig c
RIGHT JOIN relveipec a on a.idPeca = c.idPeca 
INNER JOIN veiculo v on v.idVeiculo=a.idVeiculo
WHERE not(c.idPeca is null)
GROUP BY a.idVeiculo 
HAVING count(a.idVeiculo) = (SELECT count(idPeca) FROM pecaobrig)
```

*Para otimizar crie um* `StoredProcedure`

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test1`.`VeiculosComPecasObrigatorias` ()
BEGIN

    DECLARE qtde int;
    SET qtde = (SELECT count(idPeca) FROM pecaobrig);

    SELECT v.* FROM pecaobrig c
    RIGHT JOIN relveipec a on a.idPeca = c.idPeca 
    INNER JOIN veiculo v on v.idVeiculo=a.idVeiculo
    WHERE not(c.idPeca is null)
    GROUP BY a.idVeiculo 
    HAVING count(a.idVeiculo) = qtde;          
END
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda João, gostei da ideia de criar um StoredProcedure, não havia pensado nisso.